# Better to fully liquidate and then reallocate position (partially back into same asset) if earlier holdings cost basis lower?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax

Say I have $1,000 in stock X and I'd like to rotate $500 into stock Y. If cost basis for earlier shares are lower (and taxes are assessed via first in, first out for sales), selling $500 of stock X to buy stock Y would incur N taxes. If present all-in position of X is flat or in slightly negative return, it seems it would make sense to fully liquidate $1,000 of stock X, rebuy $500 instantly, and use the remaining $500 to buy stock Y, in this way avoiding the taxes incurred by the lower cost basis associated with earlier shares. Am I missing something here?

Ignoring complications around long vs short term cap gains, it seems like if net profit of all in position is lower than the gain from partial sale, you should always fully liquidate, rebuy, and rotate rather than partially rotating?

Does this run into the wash sale rule? My understanding is that it applies only for claiming the losses as a tax reduction? This sounds slightly different than my intention... but if it does apply, does this make sense for very slightly in profit sales?

Answer (score 1):

> (and taxes are assessed via first in, first out for sales)

That's really up to you. In the US, you can *choose* which lot you're liquidating, it doesn't have to be the default FIFO. So if later lots have less gains and you're optimizing for taxes - sell the later lots.

> Does this run into the wash sale rule?

Yes, if you sell a position at a loss and then buy a replacement share within 30 days you'll have a wash sale. Your intentions don't matter.

If you only sell shares X at a loss, and keep the shares X which have gains, and then buy shares Y with the proceeds - you're fine (assuming X and Y are not substantially identical, and you haven't purchased X within 30 days before the sale).

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that it applies only for claiming the losses as a tax reduction?

In a sense, you're right - the wash sale rule just *defers* the ability to take a deduction for the loss until you exit the position (again). It does not prevent you from actually making the trade or prevent you from claiming the loss in the future.

However, given that you can choose which lots of X to sell, it makes no sense to sell everything and then re-buy to try and game your cost basis, and have to deal with it being reported as a wash sale (whether it actually affects your taxes or not). Just sell whichever lots fits your tax situation best (whether at a gain or a loss, long-term or short-term), buy the same amount of Y and be on your way.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by selling which lots fit me best. Assuming holdings are in a single account, which ever are sold are assumed to be the first in, no? I can't pick and choose which cost basis stock X is sold?

Comment: Yes you can choose the lots - you aren't locked into FIFO. You _broker_ may assume that when reporting, but that's not what you have to report on your taxes. You can choose the once that are oldest if you want long-term gains, or the ones with the largest loss if you want to offset gains, or the ones with the largest gains if you have other losses and can "harvest" gains at a lower rate.

Comment: @DStanley: you can choose lot(s) to sell, but since EESA08 mandatory basis reporting (implemented 2011-14 depending) (unless you still use paper certificates which is costly or impossible) you must _inform the broker in advance or at the time of the sale_ not later e.g. when you prepare your return. They must report it on 1099 as you chose, and you must use that reported basis (and holding date(s)). 26CFR1012.1(c) allows the broker to accept 'identification' up to settlement (now mostly T+1) but every one I've used requires it at or before order entry.

Answer (score 0):

A wash sale occurs if you liquidate an option or equity position for a loss and you buy replacement shares within 30 days before or after realizing the loss. If you buy shares that are not substantially identical, there is no wash sale.

When it comes to taxes, brokers default to FIFO (first in, first out). In the US, if you have multiple lots purchased at different prices, you can designate which shares are sold when selling a portion of them.  If you want to reduce your tax burden, you could sell the shares with the lowest cost basis.  If you want to minimize the tax burden, sell highest cost basis shares.

It makes no sense to sell appreciated shares only to rebuy them immediately (your comment about selling $1,000 of X and rebuying instantly).  All this does is add some minor slippage and fees and create a taxable event for no reason. You cannot alter the taxes due by repurchasing shares.